# EXCEL: Formulário com preenchimento em locais especificos

Tags: vba, algoritmo, excel-vba, microsoft-excel

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem tenho 7 "blocos" para serem preenchidos via formulario, eles estao lado a lado.
Como eu faco em vba uma função que preencha esses campos em branco de TM1 e TM2 automaticamente, quero incluir essa função em um formulário para preenchimento com botão avancar e voltar, são mais ou menos uns 100 blocos desse pra ser preenchidos via formulário.

Comment: Estes campos serão preenchidos com o mesmo dado? Ou dados diferentes?

Comment: Serao placares da rodada de futebol.
Cada tabela dessa com znome sera uma tabela com 10 jogos e os valores sao variados, 1x0; 2x0; 1x3; etc...
Vou ter um formulario onde coloca-se apenas os placares e o formulario preencha essas tabelas.

sao 7 tebelas mas nao sei como fazer o formulario preencher exatamente os campos em branco e depois pular para as outras 7 tabelas abaixo e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Não entendi a explicação, se puder fazer um [mcve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ajudaria. É um campeonato mata-mata?